# NewRandomAccessFile failed to create/open ; Attention_OCR

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, ocr

I am using a pretrained model by TensorFlow , Attention ocr https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/attention_ocr

While running eval.py the script always runs into an error
`File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\envs\python35DL\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: D:\Vision_Project\attention_ocr\python\data/fsns\charset_size=134.txt : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process`

I am unable to understand which path it cannot find , where and how do I fix this in the script .

System Configurations (if it matters)  : 
Windows 10 , 8gb RAM , Core i3 , 1 TB HDD
Tensorflow Version : 1.8.0
Python Version : 3.5 running through VirtualEnv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug - `fsns.py` uses Linux separator for a part of the path. Here is the [fix](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/4954/commits/6453bb534be3403aa6c2dbb112a1545da03581f7).

Please try and let me know if it helped.
Hopefully it will be merged soon.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.. the system can't find the specific files.

After I print out the exact file name string read by the system, I found out that there are some '**\n**' in the file name...

Problem solved after I do **line.rstrip()** .